# Phonegap Geolocation not working

Tags: android, geolocation, cordova

I'm using Phonegap.Geolocation to get the current position of the user.

And I've found [this example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) in the documentation from the official website.

However, even thought the onDevice ready is executed, neither success nor error function callback is executed. And I'm really confused by this.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
      alert('deviceready');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it is working, however the location cannot be determined in a short time so neither can it be deemed as success nor fail, and thus no action is performed.

This can be managed by setting a time-out for the callback of GeoLocation

Comment: I can't seem to get a successful response with this it always timesout. did you manage to anything working in the end?

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide specific answer. I expect it to be some external issues about your phone rather than the program.

Answer (score 19):

1. Make sure youryou installed the geolocation plugin (run `phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation`), and that GPS is enabled in the device.
2. Add a timeout and set enableHighAccuracy:

   ```
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
   ```

   In certain emulators you need to set enableHighAccuracy to false, so try that if still doesn't work.
3. If you are using an Android emulator, it doesn’t read GPS values, so we need to send them via command line. We need to start a telnet session in the port that the emulator is running (you can check the port in the emulator window title, the number at the beginning, in my case 5554):

   ```
   telnet localhost 5554
   ```

And then run the command

```
    geo fix -122.4 37.78
```

If you close the app you need to re-send the geolocation, so if it doesn’t work, just run the `geo fix` command just after opening the app, before the timeout event fires.

Comment: The plugin has been renamed, the command is now `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`

Answer (score 5):

When there is a phonegap feature not working, check if the corresponding permission in the app is set. e.g for internet access, or geoposition on an android-device your AndroidManifest.xml must contain following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I too struggled with this problem [thats how I got to this page]

But it finally worked. I just made on change:

I changed this line : navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

to this : navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);

and the whole thing now works.

Comment: This comment helped me. But what is the real issue behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the browser.
Clear the browser cache and run it again.

src : http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/geolocation_works_with_one_android_device_but_not_another

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the javascript in body rather than in head section of the html. I learned it the hard way, after finding no clue over the internet, so thought it would be best to share. It worked like charm for me asap, I shifted the javascript code from  to

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhoneGap Desktop and have no direct access to AndroidManifest.xml, the solution is to add the permission configurations by adding "config-file" element to config.xml.

In your project's config.xml, add the lines below:

```
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</config-file>
```

Also, make sure to to declare the android xml namespace in the widget element of your config.xml:

```
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

More details here: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/